# Why derivative of $\sqrt[x]{x}$ can be written as $(\exp(\frac{1}{x}\log(x)))'$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I simply cannot understand why the derivative of $\sqrt[x]{x}$ can be written as $(\exp(\frac{1}{x}\log(x)))'$?

Also, is that $\log$ the natural log or what?

Comment: What's your definition of $x^{1/x}$?

Answer (score 1):

It is the natural log, yes. Notice that what you want to derive is the same thing as $x^{1/x}=e^{\ln(x^{1/x})}=e^{(1/x)\ln(x)}$. Now derive the latter expression...

Comment: Because of the log properties: $log(a^b) = b log(a)$, right?

Comment: $u(x) = e^{log(u(x))}$...

Comment: We usually use this technique when we want to derive an expression of the form $u(x)^{v(x)}$, since it reduces our problem to the derivative of an exponential funtions

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^{1/x})=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\log(x^{1/x})})=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{1/x\log{x}})$$

Comment: I would  explain each step to make it more clear for the questioner, otherwise it is hard to understand how $x^{1/x}$ can be changed into $e^{log x^{1/x}}$

Comment: @MorganWeiss I think now the answer is clear

Answer (score 0):

We learn the meaning of the expression $a^b$ first when $b$ is a positive integer, next when $b$ is zero, next a negative integer, next the reciprocal of an integer, and next when $b$ is a rational number. Each time the definition is consistent with all the previous cases. If $b$ is not rational we need to take a further step (still consistent with the previous cases):
$$a^b = e^{b \log(a)}
$$
That is the **definition** of $a^b$ (and yes, $\log(\cdot)$ means the natural logarithm). So
$$\sqrt[x]{x} = x^{1/x} = e^{(1/x) \log(x)}
$$